# How to remove unnecessary blank namespace and add namespace prefix in tSQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2005, xml-namespaces

When I run my Query the namespace is added with the root element but with the second element I have xmlns="" as well... and I would like to remove that... and I need to add namespace prefix to some elements.

I provided an example:

```
declare @xml_h as xml
declare @xml_d as xml

select @xml_h = (
    select NewID() as [UID]
    for XML PATH('Head')
    )

select @xml_d = (
    select NULL, 
    (
        select 'V00001' as [ID],
            'Some name' as [Name]
        for XML PATH('SubData'), TYPE
    )
    for XML PATH('Data')
    )

;with XmlNameSpaces (DEFAULT 'uri_1', 'uri_2' as t)
select @xml_h, @xml_d for XML PATH(''), ROOT('ROOT')
```

The result being:

```
<ROOT xmlns:t="uri_2" xmlns="uri_1">
    <Head xmlns="">
        <UID>B12B8836-2061-4934-AC06-67D34579D1A6</UID>
    </Head>
    <Data xmlns="">
        <SubData>
            <ID>V00001</ID>
            <Name>Some name</Name>
        </SubData>
    </Data>
</ROOT>
```

But I need this:

```
<ROOT xmlns:t="uri_2" xmlns="uri_1">
    <Head>
        <t:UID>B12B8836-2061-4934-AC06-67D34579D1A6</t:UID>
    </Head>
    <Data>
        <t:SubData>
            <t:ID>V00001</t:ID>
            <t:Name>Some name</t:Name>
        </t:SubData>
    </Data>
</ROOT>
```

Is there any way to remove unnecessary blank namespace and add namespace prefix?

thanks

Comment: May be you can just add `t:` to column names in the query like `...   select NewID() as [t:UID] ` an so on? How should sql server know that the namespace prefix is?

Answer (score 0):

This will build a XML that is equivalent to the one you want.

```sql
declare @xml_h as xml
declare @xml_d as xml

;with XmlNameSpaces (DEFAULT 'uri_1', 'uri_2' as t)
select @xml_h = (
    select NewID() as [t.UID]
    for XML PATH('Head')
    )

;with XmlNameSpaces (DEFAULT 'uri_1', 'uri_2' as t)
select @xml_d = (
    select NULL, 
    (
        select 'V00001' as [t.ID],
            'Some name' as [t.Name]
        for XML PATH('t.SubData'), TYPE
    )
    for XML PATH('Data')
    )

;with XmlNameSpaces (DEFAULT 'uri_1', 'uri_2' as t)
select @xml_h, @xml_d for XML PATH(''), ROOT('ROOT')
```

```xml
<ROOT xmlns:t="uri_2" xmlns="uri_1">
  <Head xmlns:t="uri_2" xmlns="uri_1">
    <t.UID>ABBECBF4-59BE-46DF-B42E-4325748E0079</t.UID>
  </Head>
  <Data xmlns:t="uri_2" xmlns="uri_1">
    <t.SubData xmlns:t="uri_2" xmlns="uri_1">
      <t.ID>V00001</t.ID>
      <t.Name>Some name</t.Name>
    </t.SubData>
  </Data>
</ROOT>
```

As you can see there are namespace declarations repeated in the sub-elements. If you really have a problem with that you could either rewrite your query to use [EXPLICIT Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189068.aspx) or you can add your vote to [this connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/265956/suppress-namespace-attributes-in-nested-select-for-xml-statements) and hope for it to be a part of a future release of SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Finaly, I had to rewrite query for use with EXPLICIT mode.